# Spikes in visits to certain questions

Tags: discussion

I noticed that for the last couple of weeks, most of the questions get between 15-50 visits. But two recent, non-sequential questions suddenly have more than 500 visits. The votes are not correspondingly high. What is the cause of these spikes? Could it be bots based on key words?

The two questions I reference are:

[How to programmatically distinguish European from non European call sign?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/9311/how-to-programmatically-distinguish-european-from-non-european-call-sign) with over 600 views

[What might this tower be used for?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/9304/what-might-this-tower-be-used-for) with over 500 visits.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably just the question happening to attract some interest from people who don't participate on the site, either:

- it is interesting to them but they don't want to create an account and vote, or
- the question or answers contain phrases that people are searching for, so they turn up in search results. These people might not even be interested in amateur radio topics, but just clicking through everything that might be what they're actually looking for.

Views don't really say a lot because there can be all sorts of reasons for them. I would recommend not worrying about them.

Comment: Not worry but rather fascination. The counts are more than 10 times that of adjacent questions. They eclipse the most popular questions prior to this. If we understood the underlying reasons, we could perhaps exploit them to the advantage of the site.

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the questions was also posted on Reddit. (I won't link to it but you can find it by searching for the question title.) Maybe lots of Redditors thought it would be interesting and searched for the same thing, then landed here?